# Find the intersection between line and sphere geometrically

Tags: vector-spaces

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc7qn.png)

In this image, having a vector $B$, which intersecates a sphere of a known center $A$ and known radius $AD$, I need to find the coordinates of the vector D. I also know:

- $ACF$ is 90°
- the point D is the intersection between the sphere and the straight line that pass throught $A$ and $C$

I know that I just need to put on a system the equation of the sphere and the straight line $B$ but I'm wondering if there's a way to solve it in a geometrical way, because it would be really easier to be to put the formula into my program.

[here](https://uploadfiles.io/7wi40) there's the geogebra file if it could help

Comment: Please explain what are $A,B,C,D$ wrt the sphere.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I thought the image was clear enoght, however, now should be ok.

Comment: I guess that the origin is $F$.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just fixed

Comment: If the radius is unknown, $D$ is undertermined. If the coordinates of $B$ are unknown, knowledge of $AFB$ is insufficient and $D$ is undeterminate.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it's not. Every element I mentioned is known.

Comment: Ok, so if $D$ is known, you are done.

Comment: Why do you provide the angle $AFB$ if $A,F$ and $B$ are known ?? Please be rigorous about the given.

Comment: Yeah, actually it's a repetition...

Comment: Now it should be ok....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ABDF$ are coplanar and $AD$ is perpendicular to $FB$.

Let

$$\vec{AD}=\lambda\vec{AB}+\mu\vec{AF}.$$

We have

$$\vec{AD}\cdot\vec{FB}=0=\lambda\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{FB}+\mu\vec{AF}\cdot\vec{FB}$$

and

$$\vec{AD}^2=r^2=(\lambda\vec{AB}+\mu\vec{AF})^2=\lambda^2\left(\vec{AB}-\frac{\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{FB}}{\vec{AF}\cdot \vec{FB}}\vec{AF}\right)^2$$ from which you draw $\lambda$.